# Computing percentages (by year) from my LINQ query

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I need statistics about the usage of `Source` for the last 5 years. The LINQ query below allows me to get the job partially done.

```
public class Source
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }  
}

public class Suite
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedTime  { get; set; }
    public int SourceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Source Source { get; set; }
}

var limit = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-5).Year;
var data = _contextProvider.Context.Suites
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.CreatedTime.Year, x.SourceId })
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Year = x.Key.Year,
                SourceId = x.Key.SourceId,
                Count = x.Count()
            })
            .Where(x => x.Year >= limit)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Year).ToList();
```

The results of this LINQ query is showed below:

[image]

Now I need to go a little further: I need the percentage usage of `SourceId` by year.

**Example for 2018:**

As you can see in 2018 there are a total of 51 elements (32+12+7). This total allows me to compute percentage for each SourceId for the year. Like this:

- { Year = 2018, SourceId = 2, Percent =  63 }
- { Year = 2018, SourceId = 6, Percent =  23 }
- { Year = 2018, SourceId = 3, Percent =  14 }

**So my question is how to get these percentages from my `data` object ? Maybe is it possible to compute these percentages directly in my base LINQ query ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're definitely close. We can get to the statistics you want by breaking up the group by into two steps.

Here's the final query in all (I promise nothing about its speed in SQL! :)

```
Suites
    .Where(x => x.Created.Year >= 2013)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Created.Year)
    .Select(x => new {
        Total = x.Count(),
        Year = x.Key,
        Sources = x.GroupBy(i => i.SourceId)
            .Select(i => new {
                ItemCount = i.Count(),
                Source = i.Key })
    }).SelectMany(x => x.Sources.Select(s => new {
        TotalItems = x.Total,
        x.Year,
        s.ItemCount,
        Percent = (double)s.ItemCount / x.Total,
        SourceId = s.Source}))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Year)
    .ThenBy(x => x.SourceId)
```

The way this works is we first group by the year since that's your outer-most grouping.

This gives us two groups (In the case of my data) for `2018 - [items]` and `2017 - [items]`.

Then out of that we select out our top-level information which will be the full `Total` as well as the `Year`. For the individual lines however, we need to do another grouping. So when we take the list of items we apply our second grouping by SourceId which will let us get a line count for each source under a given year.

This gives us for 2018:

> 2018
>
> - 2, [Items]
> - 3, [Items]
> - 6, [Items]

We then Select on each of these groups and flatten them out into the key and counts which gives us the following:

> 2018
>
> - SourceId, Count
> - 2,         32
> - 3,         7
> - 6,         12

And this same structure is repeated for the year 2017 as well.

Next we want to flatten this out so we have the top-level grouping data repeated against each SourceId/Count that's been generated under each year. SelectMany is perfect for this as it takes an enumerable of enumerables and returns a single, flattened list.

Basically, we say that for every Year Group: Select everything underneath it (3-6 different SourceId/Count sets) and concatenate them all together into one list.

When we're doing this concatenation step, we can apply a `Select` to the line that's coming out to get our final count.

This gives us a final set of data that looks like:

> Year, Total, Count, Percent, SourceId
>
> 2018, 51,    32,    .627,    2
>
> 2018, 51,    7,     .137,    3
>
> 2018, 51,    12,    .235,    6
>
> [Snip]

The results in LINQPad for me look like the following:

[image: Final Results]

Comment: Brilliant ! Many thanks for your explanations. It helped me a lot.